# How to reduce lock wait on postgres when upserting records

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

Hi I have a Postgres table, that gets written to when users login to my application.
The query performs an **insert on conflict** and gets called about 150 times per second and I am seeing alot of time spent in lock wait.

The query itself takes around 50ms to execute on average.

Is there a better way to improve my query to reduce lock waits?

There are two tables:

**Users**

| ID UUID (uuid) PK | Identifier (varchar(100)) | name | project (uuid FK) | Team | Attributes (json) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd-2343-errere | bob | Bob | 34543-54545-435435-5345 | Squad1 | {'age' : 29, 'tags' : ['one'] } |
| 3432-2343-234342 | geroge | George | 34543-54545-435435-5345 | Squad1 | {'age' : 43, 'tags' : ['ten'] } |
| 234343-42343-4324324 | john | John | 23434-234-4234324-432 | Squad2 | {'age' : 54, 'tags' : ['two'] } |

When the user logs in, we insert to the Users table, unless there is a conflict where the the **Identifer** and **Project** match, in that case we update the name and attributes columns.

```
INSERT INTO
  "users" ("identifier",
    "name",
    "attributes",
    "team",
    "project")
VALUES
  ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)
ON
  CONFLICT ("project",
    "identifier") DO
UPDATE
SET
  "name"="excluded"."name",
  "attributes"="excluded"."attributes"
```

There are two indexes on the table

- project_identifier (project,identifier) UNIQUE
- pkey (id) UNIQUE

Is there a better way to write this to reduce lock wait time on the table?  I was wondering if I would be better performing a batch insert, with so many queries coming in per second?

Comment: How many INSERTs and how many UPDATEs do you do per second?

Comment: I'm not sure what the split is between inserts/updates.  We get about 150 logins per second each resulting in this call.  I suspect most are updates as we don't have new users all the time.

Comment: Is each statement in its own transaction?

Comment: Yes each is its own transaction.  I've found there seems to be alot of long running queries that query the table at the same time I see this lock wait, so starting to wonder if those queries are contributing to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is only two things you can do to improve that:

1. make the statement faster, perhaps by reducing the number of indexes and triggers on the table, or by getting faster hardware
2. see that the statement is called as late in the transaction as possible, so that the lock on the row is held for the shortest possible time